# HTTP 400 error when trying to do a PayPal payment request. (file_get_contents)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment, file-get-contents

Trying to make a test cURL-less Paypal payment request but getting an error.
I am using the Sample request from the paypal Payment API docs.

```
$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'op' => 'replace',
    'path' => '/transactions/0/amount',
    'value' => 
    array (
      'total' => '18.37',
      'currency' => 'EUR',
      'details' => 
      array (
        'subtotal' => '13.37',
        'shipping' => '5.00',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'op' => 'add',
    'path' => '/transactions/0/item_list/shipping_address',
    'value' => 
    array (
      'recipient_name' => 'Anna Gruneberg',
      'line1' => 'Kathwarinenhof 1',
      'city' => 'Flensburg',
      'postal_code' => '24939',
      'country_code' => 'DE',
    ),
  ),
);

$url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment';
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => array(
            "Content-type: application/json", 
            "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
        ),
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
print_r($options);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

Return: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /storage/ssd5/910/7954910/public_html/paypal.php on line 48
bool(false)

Comment: I think you'd need to use `FALSE` (all uppercase) there as the second parameter, or `0`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
'protocol_version' => '1.1'
```

to the 'http' => array().

e.g. Change the line

```
'method'  => 'POST',
```

to

```
'protocol_version'  => '1.1',
'method'  => 'POST',
```

This changes the HTTP protocol used by file_get_contents() from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1, and HTTP/1.1 is required by the PayPal REST API server.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer would benefit from an explanation of why this change answers to question.